# Método para contar profesores en un archivo

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Quiero implementar un metodo en un menu que permita consultar el numero de profesores de este archivo csv, y otro metodo que permita consultar el numero de profesores de x departamento. Tambien poder cambiar o actualizar el nombre del departamento de un profesor en java. Como podria implementar dichos metodos que pide el menú?

Este es el menú que he intentado:

`código`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lectura.lecturaPosiciones();
        //Lectura.lecturaPersonas();
        
        //MENU DE OPCIONES
       Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
       boolean salir = false;
       int opcion;
       
       while(!salir){
            
           System.out.println("1. Consultar número de profesores.");
           System.out.println("2. Consultar número de profesores del departament X");
           System.out.println("3. Consultar el número de profesores de  X categoria en el departamento Y");
           System.out.println("4. Consultar cuantos profesores empezaron a trabajar en el año X");          
           System.out.println("5. Actualizar el nombre del departamento X");
           System.out.println("6. Salir");
           
           try {
            
           System.out.println("Escribe una de las opciones: \n");
           opcion = sn.nextInt();
           
           switch(opcion){
               case 1:
                   System.out.println("Has seleccionado la opción 1");
                   break;
               case 2:
                   System.out.println("Has seleccionado la opción 2");
                   break;
                case 3:
                   System.out.println("Has seleccionado la opción 3");
                   break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Has seleccionado la opción 4");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Has seleccionado la opción 5");
                    break;
                case 6:
                   salir=true;
                   break;
                default:
                   System.out.println("Solo números entre 1 y 4");
           }
           } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Debes insertar un número");
                sn.next();
            }           
       }
}
```